# PutObjectRequest exception in AWSSDK 2.0.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

After upgrading to AWSSDK 2.0.2, this block of code no longer will upload my stream to my s3 bucket. I downgraded to 1.5.39 and it works just fine. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
using (var s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
        {
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest( );
            putObjectRequest.BucketName = Settings.Default.AWSImageStore;
            putObjectRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
            putObjectRequest.Key = fileName;
            putObjectRequest.InputStream = imageStream;
            PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
            response.Dispose();
        }
```

I get a generic amazon exception and the inner exception says "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write to a stream, the stream's pointer is left at the end by default.  In the 1.5 version of the SDK, the SDK moved the pointer back to the beginning for you.  In 2.0, you need to seek back to the beginning before calling PutObjectResponse:

```
using (var s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
    {
        if(imageStream.CanSeek)
        {
            imageStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest( );
        putObjectRequest.BucketName = Settings.Default.AWSImageStore;
        putObjectRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
        putObjectRequest.Key = fileName;
        putObjectRequest.InputStream = imageStream;
        PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
        response.Dispose();
    }
```